# Minimize distance to hyperplane given set of points

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-programming, plane-geometry

I have two points that are used to create a parametric line equation. One of this points is on hyperplane and a set of points that are on one side of that hyperplane. How can I rotate hyperplane in such a way that it still passes point previously mentioned and minimise the distance to this hyperplane for the set of points.

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret the sentence "one of this points is on hyperplane and a set of points that are on one side of that hyperplane".  Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have two points, lets say M and X. I have constructed a parametric line equation on that two points. After I have Constructed a plane equation that is orthogonal to the line MX and goes through point M. Aside this two points I have a set points, that lie on one side of this plane. So the plane constructed is a separating plane

Comment: Do you mean that the point $X$ and the set of points lie on opposite sides of the hyperplane?

Comment: Also, what are the requirements on the rotated hyperplane?  Is the rotated hyperplane also supposed to be a separating plane between $X$ and the set of points?

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by the distance of a set of points, from a hyperplane? If $H$ is the hyperplane and $A$ is the set, are you referrring to, say, $$\inf_{\substack{a \in A \\ h \in H}} \|a - h\|?$$ Or perhaps, $$\sup_{a \in A} \inf_{h \in H} \|a - h\|?$$

Comment: @user744868 the first definition is standard in this context

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The set of points and X lie on the same side of the plane. The only requirement is that rotated plane must minimise the mean distance of set of points and must pass point M

Comment: @Student if they lie on the same side, then in what sense is it a "separating hyperplane"?  Is that the mean distance to all points including $X$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I had a bigger set of points and selected only those that lie on the same side as X

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that's the mean of point from the set, without X

Comment: @Student Presumably, then, you could take the hyperplane perpendicular to the line connecting $M$ and the mean point of the set.  Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, thanks. I will try this approach.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you please also recommend, is there any formula, where I can construct a plane under certain angle to the parametric line?

Comment: @Student It's easy to construct a plane perpendicular to a given line; we simply use the vector's components as coefficients.  Note that there is generally not a unique plane that has a certain angle to a parametric line.  Probably the best approach is to take a vector whose angle with the line is the complement of the desired angle, then take the hyperplane perpendicular to your vector.